# Reputation decrease not shown in recent achievements icon

Tags: support, reputation

I suspect my reputation has decreased before without any visible notice, but now I'm sure of it. I had a 1296 reputation score 3 days ago. In the middle of the weekend it dropped to 1292 (-4). At first I kept thinking that I was wrong, I've never had 1296, because the recent achievements icon I see on the top of the site did not show any decrease in my reputation in the last 7 days. But today I accessed Travel SE from a different computer and before I refreshed the page there was my 1296 reputation score. Naturally after the refresh it went to 1292.

In short, my question is: why can my reputation decrease and it not be show in the recent achievements?

Comment: The only event that was never counted for me was an "unvote", i.e. someone upvoted your answer and de-upvoted it. But the difference of 4 points does not match such an event.

Comment: @Vince, perhaps 2 of those events happened very close in time? Anyway, why is that not shown in recent achievements?

Comment: Maybe, the 4 points difference could be two "de-downvote". Why? Good question, I've wondered the same before, I am not sure there is any logic, especially as "unaccepted" is an event that appears.

Comment: @Vince Probably the point count in the question is still positive, that is, I got an upvote that means +10, now I got a downvote (-2) that means I still earned +8 points. Perhaps "Recent Achievements" is showing +8 and not -2. If it is, doesn't seem adequate, at least to me.

Comment: Oops, no two de-downvotes would not work, sorry I was not thinking. Yeah I really don't know what it could be for a 4 points difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two posts where you had approved suggested edits have been deleted, so the 2 rep you got for each of them has evaporated (when a post is deleted, the reputation associated with it is also gone).

You can see such changed by checking the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your profile page reputation tab.

I suppose there are other ways for this to happen (deleted answer with 1 upvote and 3 downvotes, for instance).

The way to think about this reputation (for posts that have been deleted) is as if it was never there. Those are reputation points that no longer exist.

We do not show deleted items in the achievements drop down.

Comment: Wait a minute. We learned in the other thread that they stay on your transcript forever, even if the question is deleted.